# Perguntas "Apresentado"?

Tags: debate

Na barra de navegação aparece "apresentado" como tradução de featured. Penso que "apresentado" não diz nada a ninguém sobre o que significa, para além de que o género da palavra apresentado é masculino e por isso não concorda com o género e o número da palavra "perguntas"

"Em destaque" (perguntas em destaque) não seria uma melhor tradução para "Featured"?